# Why does this CSS transition queue?

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-transitions

When I hover over the `div` the colour change happens on the `div` content *before* the colour change affects the `span`. Why is this and how can I have it so both animations happen simultaneously? The reason for the `* { transition: ... }` is so that every element of a site is animated by default in case its properties ever change.

http://jsfiddle.net/wf63jquz/

HTML:

```
<div>
    <span>Hello</span>
    Hola
</div>
```

CSS:

```
*,
*:before,
*:after
{
    -moz-transition: 2s;
    -o-transition: 2s;
    -webkit-transition: 2s;
    transition: 2s;
}

div {
    color: red;
}

div:hover
{
    color: green;
}
```

***Edit***

Eugh, didn't think to check in other browsers. New question: why does Chrome do it wrong and how can I solve it for Chrome? I guess it could be a general webkit issue but I don't have quick access to Safari to check.

Comment: In what browser? Works fine here (Win7 + FF31)

Comment: I really don't understand what you're asking here, there's only one animation?

Comment: add div:hover > span to the div:hover block to make them change color at the same time on hover, but they will still fade out at different times, because your span tag effectively has two transitions applied to it.

Comment: Just updated my question, turns out this could a Chrome (webkit?) only problem.

Comment: And stuff like this is why Transitions is still in draft after so many years. Too many edge cases to account for.

Comment: Just for reference, this also happens in Opera for me.

Comment: @Callum.: Which version? If it's >= 15, then you're essentially testing in Chrome, really.

Comment: @BoltClock It's Opera 29, and it's still a different browser ^^

Comment: @Callum. he meant that both share the same engine i.e webkit ...

Answer (score 0):

Its because of * .. if you use the code like below it'll give you the desired result:

```
div:before,div:after{
-moz-transition: 2s;
-o-transition: 2s;
-webkit-transition: 2s;
transition: 2s;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after
{
    -moz-transition: 2s;
    -o-transition: 2s;
    -webkit-transition: 2s;
    transition: 2s;
}

div, span {
    color: red;
}

div:hover, span:hover
{
    color: green;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <span>Hello</span>
    Hola
</div>
```

Comment: That's actually quite good although it has the undesired effect (in Chrome) of being able to hover the `span` and seeing it animate but the `div` remains red. I change it to remove the setting the original `span` to red (see http://jsfiddle.net/wf63jquz/6/) which works better except if you flick the mouse between the two words, then the animations thoroughly upset.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue with Chrome in that it animates all of the standard HTML elements first, then after that it processes the rest of the content.

To remedy the issue, it appears that wrapping your content that's outside of a tag inside one, that works. So your HTML would be:

```
<div>
    <span>Hello</span>
    <span>Hola</span>
</div>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wf63jquz/5/)

As @Boltclock said though, these "quirks" are down to the fact that transitions are still in draft because it seems nobody has got them quite perfect *yet* :)

Comment: This looks to do some very strange things to the timings. I extended it to 5 seconds (see http://jsfiddle.net/wf63jquz/9/), it seems to wait for ages and then transition over a much shorter time.

Comment: @Chris That looks like it's stacking the animations (per hierarchy) so it seems to wait for 10 seconds (5 for the `div` transition, 5 for the `span`). Something weird going on here. My advice would be to not combine `*` with `transition`!